# Too many rcuob and rcuos are shown

Tags: process, cpu, centos7, ps

On my Linux server, Too many rcuob and rcuos process are shown.

Execute a following command.

```
ps auxwwf | grep rcu
```

And shown below.

```
root          9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     5月30   0:00  \_ [rcuob/0]
root         10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     5月30   0:00  \_ [rcuob/1]
:
:
root        151  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     5月30   0:00  \_ [rcuob/142]
root        152  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     5月30   0:00  \_ [rcuob/143]
```

and

```
root        154  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     5月30   0:11  \_ [rcuos/0]
root        155  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     5月30   0:04  \_ [rcuos/1]
:
:
root        296  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     5月30   0:00  \_ [rcuos/142]
root        297  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     5月30   0:00  \_ [rcuos/143]
```

The server's CPU is "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz"

Total Memory is "32GB"

and OS is"CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)"

I do not know what these are, and if they are the problem, please let me know the procedure to fix it.

Comment: Not a problem - please see this question for an explanation:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/523025/what-are-the-rcuos-rcuob-processes-im-seeing-in-top

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same behaviour on RHEL7.2 3.10.0-327.el7.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1404313 has the title ***More "rcuob" and "rcuos" kernel threads running than there are CPUs online***, and describes how the RCU threads started did not match the number of online CPUs, but the number of possible CPUs.  It explains a fix has been released with an errata RHSA-2016-2574, kernel 3.10.0-514.el7.  I imagine CentOS will also have a fix.

To view the number of online CPUs and the number of possible CPUs:

```
> cd /sys/devices/system/cpu ; grep '' {online,offline,possible}
online:0-55
offline:56-191
possible:0-191
```

Count the number of `rcuob` and `rcuos` kernel threads:

```
> ps aux | awk '/\[(ksoftirqd|migration|watchdog|rcuo)/{print $11}' | sed 's/[0-9]//g' | sort | uniq -c
     56 [ksoftirqd/]
     56 [migration/]
    192 [rcuob/]
    192 [rcuos/]
     56 [watchdog/]
```